# Can the invisible outline borders of controls in xcode be viewed?

Tags: ios, xcode

Sorry I'm not sure if I have the terminology correct but I'd like to see the borders of the controls I use in Xcode as I work with them on my storyboard.

For example, I have a UITextView but I'm unable to see how much space it takes up until I click it.

I'm convinced there's an option for it and a google hasn't turned up anything, probably because I'm searching for the wrong thing!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, Editor > Canvas > Show Layout Rectangles will draw a red rectangle around each view, and the baseline for views where that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the bounds of any view in the screen using this code:

```
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
```

Look you can use this for ANY view you want. Also, you can change the color and border size if you need.

If you can't see the bounds, check out if your view hasn't ambiguously layout or if the frame has defined correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use code to do this you can go into the Interface Builder and click on the desired object and in the Attribute Inspector set the background to any color.   This will not give you a border, but rather a filled rectangle over the whole area of the object which will allow you to see the objects bounds.